# Float conversion doesn't work

Tags: php, numbers

I have this function which I expected to work well for converting **strings to floats**:

```
function getFloat($value) {
    $cleanString = preg_replace('/([^0-9\.,])/i', '', $value);
    $onlyNumbersString = preg_replace('/([^0-9])/i', '', $value);

    $separatorsCountToBeErased = strlen($cleanString) - strlen($onlyNumbersString) - 1;

    $stringWithCommaOrDot = preg_replace('/([,\.])/', '', $cleanString, $separatorsCountToBeErased);
    $removedThousendSeparator = preg_replace('/(\.|,)(?=[0-9]{3,}$)/', '',  $stringWithCommaOrDot);

    return (float) str_replace(',', '.', $removedThousendSeparator);
}
```

However:

```
$str = '449.0000';
echo getFloat($str); 
// => 4490000
```

So I tried:

```
$str = '449.0000';
echo filter_var($str, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT ); 
// => 4490000
```

**Why does to they both convert `449.0000` to `449000`**?

The only thing that works here is `(float) $str` which returns `449` as expected but I need that function to get rid of alphabets spaces etc.

Comment: Ah and also, although `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT` converts the string to float, but still doesn't convert the `type`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT

```
<?php

$str = '449.0000';
$filter = filter_var($str,FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);
var_dump($filter);
if ($filter !== false) {
        $float = floatval($filter);
        var_dump($float);
}
```

Comment: Neat! It also converts the type. Thanks